# A question about a normal lower semicontinuos function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, semicontinuous-functions

**Theorem:** A lower semicontinuos function on a topological space $X$ is normal if
and only if for each real number $\lambda $, $\left\{ x\in X:f\left(
x\right) <\lambda \right\} $ is a union of regular closed sets.

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and $D$ is a dense subset of $X$.
Also $f:X\longrightarrow 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
$ is a normal lower semicontinuos function such that $f\left( x\right) $ is
positive for each $x\in D$. Then is $f(x)$ greater than or equal to zero for
each $x\in X$?

Comment: Your definition of "regular lower semi continuous" function is equivalent to the standard definition of "lower semi continuous" for any set is a union of singletons which are regular closed sets.

Comment: @blamethelag This is not true. Not regular lower semicontinuos, it is normal lower semicontinuos. any set is not regular closed. Singletons are not always regular closed sets.

Comment: How about my function? It is defined on $\mathbb R$ where singletons are regular closed. Fyi singletons are always regular and they are closed in Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: @blamethelag A subset of a topological space is called a regular closed set if it is equal to the closure of its interior.

Comment: @blamethelag The interior of singletions are empty.

Answer (score 1):

No, consider on the real line $f(x) = 0$ if $x\neq 0$ and $-1$ if $x=0$.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question

Comment: @MehmetOnat This function is lower semi continuous. You can show it with the $\epsilon$ definition, the sequential criterion, or by checking its epigraph is closed.